# Getting the sent message time from openfire to xmpp in IOS

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xmpp

How can I get the time and date of sent message from open fire to IOS simulator using XMPP framework? Right now I am getting the time in simulator when it is sent from simulator to open fire spark kit. But the time and date is returned nil when the vice versa is done.

Answer (score 3):

As specified in [XEP-203](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0203.html), XMPP message may contain optional `delay` payload with `stamp` attribute:

```
<delay xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'
             from='juliet@capulet.com/balcony'
            stamp='2002-09-10T23:41:07Z'/>
```

XMPPFramework have `NSXMLElement (XEP_0203)` category which handle that payload (and legacy format too). If `[message delayedDeliveryDate]` return `nil` value, then message does not have timestamp and you should consider to store current time as message time. Most XMPP servers adds a timestamp only when message was really delayed (e.g. message to/from offline user)